# What do "underidentification" and "point-identified" mean in econometrics?

Tags: econometrics, nonexpert

[Borusyak, 2021](https://www.mendeley.com/catalogue/b1e55330-f605-363c-b07f-3ab67325e929/?utm_source=desktop&utm_medium=1.19.8&utm_campaign=open_catalog&userDocumentId=%7B47d22c8f-e7ba-3ead-9833-eeae8a94d5f0%7D) has a sentence

> First, we note that failing to rule out anticipation effects in
> “fully-dynamic” specifications (with all leads and lags of treatment
> included) leads to an **underidentification** problem, where the
> dynamic path of anticipation and treatment effects over time is not
> **point-identified**

I am wondering what do "underidentification" and "point-identified" mean in this case? I ask these words here because these words are not in the vocabulary (I checked with Cambridge dictionary) and I believe it belongs to econometrics words.

Comment: https://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/watkins/identification.htm

Comment: Obligatory reference: [Lewbel: The Identification zoo, Journal of Economic Literature, 50, 835-903](http://www.doi.org/10.1257/jel.20181361)

Comment: @tdm: at a glance, that looks like a really useful reference. thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A parameter is "identified" if it can be known from an infinite amount of data. "Underidentified" thus means, "even if we had infinite data, we could never learn the true parameter".

"Point identified" contrasts with "set identified" with "point" meaning, "we know the exact value" and "set" meaning "we have a set and know the true value is in the set".

Comment: Thank @Michael, I am wondering if "Identified" also means if we have enough data, we will have the more precise result,  or something similar to that?

Comment: And, a very clear and great answer, thank Micheal!

Comment: "Identified" makes no comment on the variance (precision) of an estimator. "Efficiency" or a presentation of the asymptotic distribution are the key things to look for regarding precision.